# Why $\{0\}$ is not a proper subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

In Artin's Algebra, this is written:

> A subspace $W$ is called a *proper* subspace of $V$ if it is neither the whole space $V$ nor
>   the zero subspace $\{0\}$

What will be wrong if $\{0\}$ be a proper subspace?

---

I knew the word ***proper*** is used so that it is not the whole thing. Is my knowledge is wrong? (For example is it also *not* true that for any non-empty set $A$, *null set* is not a *proper subset* of $A$?).

Comment: IMHO this is just a convention. But, it is a useful one and permeates all algebra. You will meet it again when studying groups, modules et cetera. It is most useful to exclude the trivial subspace, subgroup, submodule in many cases. For example when forming quotients you won't get anything new by moding out the trivial subspace.

Comment: Usually a proper subspace is defined to be any subspace other than the whole space. May be the fact that the factor space $W/ \{0\} \equiv W$ doesn´t yield a "new" space motivates Artin to take out $\{0\}$ as well.

Comment: Usually people use the term non-trivial subspace for that and proper is reserved for subspaces different from the whole space.

Comment: This is just one example where terminology is inconsistent between different authors. And "proper" has at least two other quite different meanings that I can think of right now: proper maps in topology; and proper submanifolds-with-boundary in differential topology. Sometimes terminology does become very standard, and to tell the truth I think that this particular usage of proper --- in the context of a subset, meaning not equal to the whole set --- has moved quite close to being standard over my career. But Artin's book shows that this movement is not without countermovement.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a definition. It is just a name. You could call it "good subspace", "bad subspace", "insane subspace", "halcyon subspace", or "Moonshine subspace" instead of "proper subspace" if YOU wish.

If you are asking for the motivations behind, then you will soon learn about the usefulness of such definition while you are continuing reading the book.

Comment: I understood the point you made here, but my question was actually different(to add, may be my explanation is not right !!). **What I knew that** in convention the word *proper* is used before something (like proper subset etc) is to say everything of that type except the *whole* thing. But the definition given is saying something else. So my question was if my knowledge is **wrong or not**.

Comment: But for the comment other made assures that I was not wrong, moreover I understood why Artin's book used such definition actually. Thanks btw...

Comment: @MANMAID Well, a "proper subset" of a space could be every subspace except the whole thing. A "proper subspace" (defined by Artin) is a little bit more restrictive than that, for the sake of convenience. It is very dangerous to assume that every "proper" has the same meaning. Math authors (including you) could define the word "proper" however they wish. Examples include a "proper" model category , a "proper" embedding, and a "proper" immersion, a "proper" submanifold. I think LeeMosher answered this question well.

Answer (score 1):

$\{0\}$ is a trivial subspace of any vector space, so that's probably the reason that we call it not a proper subspace.